# How to disable 3D acceleration on the Mac Book Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, xcode, gpu

I have a Mac Book Air 2010 with an NVidia GeForce 320M chip. When I use Xcode 6 in the View Debugging tool (a 3D interface that allows debugging the view hierarchy of an app),  the computer crashes and then reports an error with GPU driver (similar bug reported [here](http://www.sandymilne.com/view-debugging-in-xcode-6-causes-mac-to-crash/)).

One solution might be to disable the 3D acceleration with a utility called `gfxCardStatus`. Unfortunately, this solution does not work for the Mac Book Air. Is there any other method to tweak the graphic driver?

Many thanks!

Comment: interesting question, it's like I could've asked it myself! ;)

Comment: The error report: 
Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
 com.apple.GeForceTesla(8.2.4)[B0074750-2FC6-3E26-BEA0-5AD5469686CF]@0xffffff7f827d6000->0xffffff7f828a0fff
 dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[2852ACFE-FD28-3C37-9B39-885201BB8D25]@0xffffff7f814bf000
 dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[D41125CE-69BD-32E7-9B1D-4E83431662DD]@0xffffff7f818be000
 dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[75D81741-64C1-3941-ADFA-9D6B6C434EE4]@0xffffff7f8187b000
 dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(8.2.4)[D61B2BB9-4289-318D-9197-5E1E13B1FF32]@0xffffff7f818ce000

Comment: @neural5torm Thanks for posting that backtrace; I found this page by searching for the UUID `B0074750-2FC6-3E26-BEA0-5AD5469686CF`. :-)

Comment: I have the same problem, I think it is/was an issue with Xcode.

Comment: Everybody who is experiencing this needs to file a Radar with Apple.  http://radar.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

One way of disabling your graphics is safe mode. I don't know if your xcode debug tool will run in safe mode but unless you know otherwise, I think it's worth a shot. good luck

[OS X: What is Safe Boot, Safe Mode?](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564?viewlocale=en_US)

> Safe Mode in Mac OS X v10.5 or later also disables Quartz Extreme (hardware accelerated graphics). Applications that depend on Quartz Extreme do not open in Safe Mode, and the Mac OS X menu bar will appear solid even if "Translucent Menu Bar" is enabled in Desktop & Screen Saver preferences.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This indeed disabled the 3-D but also the View Debugging tool :(